# TypeScript Compiler (tsc) doesn't respond on Raspberry PI

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, raspberry-pi

**My raspberry PI completely died for no reason overnight. Might have been the hardware that caused the problems.**

I can run tsc on my computer just fine, but when I try to compile on my pi 3, tsc just wont respond. I have tried to reinstall typescript and tested it on simple example code. `tsc --help` does not respond either.

Comment: No output usually means it was successfull, did you check whether it _did_ compile the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of `tsc` are you using?

I noticed something similar today making changes to my bot on a Raspberry PI 3. tsc 
Version 3.7.5, node v10.16.3, npm v6.13.4. `$ npm run build` and `$ tsc` would not respond.

After reinstalling tsc globally (`$ npm install -g tsc`) both the `$ tsc` and `$ npm run build` worked. Still the compilation times were noticeably much longer.